# Can sin(x) be the characteristic polynomial of a Homogeneous Linear Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Basically, I'm curious as to whether or not it makes sense to construct a differential operator out of the Taylor expansions of certain functions, like $\sin(x)$ or $e^x$. These would look like:

$y' - \frac{y'''}{3!} + \frac{y^{(5)}}{5!}+ \cdots= q(t)$ , where the characteristic polynomial is $\sin(x)$

$y + y' + \frac{y''}{2!} + \frac{y'''}{3!} +\cdots= q(t)$, where the characteristic polynomial is $e^x$

If these equations are constructible and solvable, how would one go about finding the solutions?

I was thinking for $\sin(x)$, which has an [infinite product representation](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/a/2/f/a2fbd73cef675cd6e61c634ada17e37c.png), you could take the Laplace transform and do a partial fraction decomposition, solving the inverse transform that way.

Is there framework that can be used to more generally solve these problems?

Comment: Your title strikes hard: is $\;\sin x\;$ *a polynomial* ? Then what are we talking about?

Comment: A polynomial in sense of a Taylor expansion. I was just wondering if the polynomial differential operator could be extended to Taylor series.

Comment: Indeed, I would write $\left(\sin\dfrac{d}{dx}\right) y$ or $e^{d/dx} y$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [pseudo-differential operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-differential_operator).